# Prawn does not render a PDF on Heroku, but does it local

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, prawn

As the title says: My PDFs are perfectly rendered when I run on my server locally, but on Heroku I get a `NoMethodError`. It seems that Heroku cannot find my prawn gem. I am using the `prawn-rails` gem.

Any ideas?

I have uploaded the complete callstack here: http://f.cl.ly/items/2g232h3U0B2G0k0i0S1y/Action%20Controller%20%20Exception%20caught.html

Comment: Does prawn require saving the pdf to disk before sending to client?

Comment: You can definitely process PDFs with free Heroku. I do it with wkhtmltopdf-based WickedPDF on their 1.8.7 stack.

Comment: agreed - the prawn site itself runs on Heroku!!! http://prawn.heroku.com/

Comment: It worked before they upgraded their stack and there are several other apps that use Prawn on Heroku.

Comment: The problem is in fact here `.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/prawn-0.11.1/lib/prawn/font/afm.rb:91:in \`normalize_encoding'`. So prawn is loaded and (partly) working. This may hint at a bug in prawn, though.

Comment: @d135-1r43: you're creating your pdf with free heroku?

Comment: Yes, I am using the free plan, but I have solved the problem as you can see in my own answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved. It seems as Heroku does not have a "Helvetica".